# react-native-collapsible-tab-view - switching between tabs is very slow to react , while sliding between them is smooth

Tags: reactjs, react-native, animation, react-native-reanimated, react-native-reanimated-v2

I'm using [react-native-collapsible-tab-view](https://github.com/PedroBern/react-native-collapsible-tab-view) in my sample project. I'm having a issue in switching the tabs, when i am sliding between tabs they are fine but when i press on a particular tab the performance is very slow and animation on the tabs is also slow.video is also attached in reference of the issue. Please help me out.

[image]